# iterating over PagedListHolder in jsp

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

How can I process PagedListHolder in JSP?

In my controller I have this:

```
PagedListHolder<Logo> pagedListHolder = new PagedListHolder<Logo>(listLogo);
pagedListHolder.setPageSize(2);
```

and in my jsp:

```
<c:forEach items="${pagedListHolder}" var="listHolderItem">
```

But it does not work. JSTL can not iterate over pagedListHolder;

#

newer mind, I got it:

in order to process PagedListHolder list you need to get de list back from the PagedListHolder. This is how you do it:

```
PagedListHolder<Logo> pagedListHolder = new PagedListHolder<Logo>(listLogo);
pagedListHolder.setPageSize(2);

List<Logo> pagedListLogo = pagedListHolder.getPageList();

model.addAttribute("pagedListLogo", pagedListLogo);
```

in your jsp:

```
<c:forEach items="${pagedListLogo}" var="logo">
...
```

voila, it works. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you noted, you should get the list. Two ways to do that:

- in the controller, with `model.addAttribute("list", pagedList.getPageList())`
- in the JSP, with `<c:forEach items="${list.pageList}">`

Comment: indeed, that works too. I just forgot that jstl is case sensitive :)